# Django: Parent object has no attribute children_set

Tags: python, django, model

I have these two **models**:

```py
class Periodo(models.Model):
    # id usato per identificare i documenti
    # periodo rilevato in fattura
    data_i_p = models.DateField('data inizio', blank=True)
    data_f_p = models.DateField('data fine ', blank=True)
    mc_p = models.DecimalField('mc', max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, blank=True, default=0)
    idfatt = models.ForeignKey(FattAqp, verbose_name="fattura AQP", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='periodo_rel')
    descr = models.CharField('descrizione', max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Periodo'
```

```py
class DettFAqp(models.Model):
    imponibile = models.DecimalField('imponibile', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    iva = models.DecimalField('%IVA', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=10)
    mc = models.DecimalField('qtà (gg/mc)', max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, blank=True, default=0)
    voce = models.ForeignKey(VoceAqp, verbose_name="metodo di ripart.", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    periodo = models.ForeignKey(Periodo, verbose_name="Periodo in fattura", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='dettfaqp', help_text=u"periodo cui la voce appartiene")
    rigo = models.DecimalField('rigo', max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default=0, help_text=u"rigo di fattura")
```

When I try to access the set related to the parent I get the following error:

```
>>> p=Periodo.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> p
<Periodo: consumo accertato in 344 gg>
>>> p.dettfaqp_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    p.dettfaqp_set.all()
AttributeError: 'Periodo' object has no attribute 'dettfaqp_set'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `related_name` attribute you don't need to include **_set** at the end of calling it: just use this:

```
p.dettfaqp.all()
```

and it should work.

Only use **_set** if you havent specified the `related_name` for the `ForeignKey`, in your example it would be:

```
p.periodo_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `related_name` for `DettFAqp.periodo` to `"dettfaqp"`. You should use that property instead. `p.dettfaqp.all()`

Answer (score 0):

You specified a [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class DettFAqp(models.Model):
   # …
   periodo = models.ForeignKey(
       Periodo,
       verbose_name='Periodo in fattura',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       related_name='dettfaqp',
       help_text='periodo cui la voce appartiene'
    )
```

This thus means that the relation in reverse is no longer `dettfaqp_set`, but `dettfaqp`, you thus access this with:

```
p.dettfaqp.all()
```